# Irreducibility for polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[i][X]$

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

How can one show that the polynomial:

$$
f= (2+i)X^4 + 5X^2 - 3i \hspace{15px}\text{with coefficients in } \mathbb{Z}[i]
$$

is reducible/irreducible. I know about the Eisenstein criterion and the reduction criterion, but I can't seem to get a grasp on how to apply these in a useful way.

Comment: Not sure if this works, but maybe use that $\mathbb{Z}[i][X]\cong\frac{\mathbb{Z}[X, Y]}{(Y^2+1)}$ and replace $i$ with $Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplying with $(2-i)/5$ we obtain a monic polynomial of degree $4$. Setting $x=X^2$ it is a quadratic polynomial. Suppose it is of the form $(x+a+bi)(x+c+di)$ and compare coefficients. One obtains easy  Diophantine equations in $a,b,c,d$. One of them is
$$
5(a^2+2a-b^2+b)=3,
$$
a contradiction, because $5$ does not divide $3$. Hence the polynomial is indeed irreducible.